# How to copy a array in node without reference and JSON parse/stringify

Tags: arrays, node.js, pointers, reference, clone

I want to copy a global static array to individualise the array to each user session.

I tryed to copy that array with `concat/slice/[...array]` but it takes every time the same reference / pointer. Only with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` it seems to work.

Is there a more efficient way to copy a array / object / variable without geting the reference / pointer with it

```
var Array2 = [...Array];

var Array2 = Array.concat();

var Array2 = Array.slice();

dosent work.

var Array = [{
   test: 'i am a test'
}]


var Array2 = Array;

Array2.favorite = true;

console.log(Array) //result: test: 'i am a test', favorite: true

var Array3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array)); 

console.log(Array) //result: test: 'i am a test'
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to perform a deep copy of an object in javascript, but believe me, the most widely used is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array))`. What are your concerns with that method? Realistically, if your concerns are with performance, you shouldn't be performing regular deep copies of objects _period_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you trying to do is - clone the array content. So you have few options:

1. Use lodash

   - `var newArr = _.cloneDeep(originalArr)`
2. If you are sure, you have just simple objects - you may use something like:

   - `var newArr = originalArr.map(d => Object.assign({}, d))`
3. In case the structure is well known - you may write `cloneFunction` for the structure, than use your own clone with `originalArr.map(cloneFunction)`